# How to play HLS in windows phone (Not SmoothStreaming)?

Tags: video-streaming, windows-phone, http-live-streaming

I need to play HLS video stream in Windows Phone (no metter version). So, how I can do it? Maybe any third party solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may also try http://phonesm.codeplex.com/

It should allow to play m3u8 hls streams (example that streams NASA TV's live .m3u8 feed is included)

Answer (score 2):

The [3ivx HLS Adapter](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html) for Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 allows apps to be written which can use HTTP Live Streaming

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone does not include native support for HLS. (Well, it is Apple's technology)

I do know that there are apps in the marketplace/store which allow the streaming of some HLS content there are no available 3rd party solutions that I'm aware of.